# How to set-up JW Player to play HLS on iPhone using HTML5

Tags: iphone, html, jwplayer

I am using JW player 7.8. I am trying to set the player to play my live stream inside JW player, and it should be playable on iPhone.

To my understanding, I have to use HTML5 version of JW Player. I have a HLS source: `http://server-ip:1935/live/mystream/playlist.m3u8` and my javascript code looks something like this:

```
jwplayer('my-stream').setup({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  stretching: 'uniform',
  playlist: [{
    sources: [{
      file: 'http://server-ip:1935/live/mystream/playlist.m3u8'
    }}]
  }],
  primary: 'html5',
  modes: [
    { type: "html5" },
    { type: "flash", src: "player.swf" }
  ]
});
```

And I am getting an error on my iPhone:

`Error loading media: File could not be played`

I have found how to test it with site: http://demo.jwplayer.com/developer-tools/http-stream-tester/ but still no luck in playing the m3u8 file on iPhone. (Should I change the file type?)

I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: JW Player should handle this automatically.

If you go to http://server-ip:1935/live/mystream/playlist.m3u8 in Safari on the iPhone, does it play there?

Comment: The issue is somewhere else. The bad encoder was used so the generated playlist.m3u3 source couldn't be played in HLS format. That was the reason at the end. But thanks for the time to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="CLOUD_HOSTED_PLAYER.js"></script> 
// It should be 7.8.7 at the time of writing
<div id="container">Loading Video...</div>
<script>
    var playerone = jwplayer("container");
    playerone.setup({
        file: "http://server-ip:1935/live/mystream/playlist.m3u8",
        width:"80%",
        aspectratio:"16:9"
    });
</script>
```